# How to determine what JavaScript causes a browser crash?

Tags: javascript, crash

I'm brand new to JavaScript, and have a crashing application. I have no idea what would cause the crash.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
//constants

var Col = 20, Rows = 20;

var cellHeight = 25;

    var cellWidth = 25;

    var foodX;

    var score;

    var foodY;

    var Nothing = 0, Snake = 1, Food = 2;

    var Left = 37, Up = 38, Right = 39, Down = 40;

    var canvas = document.getElementById('snakeCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var dead = "false";

    var snakeDirection = null;

    var keystate;

    var snake = [];

    function start() //this is where we begin the long journey
    {

    init();     

    Tick();

    }

    function init() {
        snake = [{ x: 5, y: 5 }];

        snakeDirection = null;

        score = 0;

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

        setFood();

        keystate = null;

    }

    function Tick()     // just liker a timer tick
    {

        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
            keystate = evt.keyCode;              // checks key presses
        });

        //document.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
            //delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
        //});





        update();  //after we check for a key press we update alllll the      
                                  stuff



        setTimeout(Tick, 300);

        //}

    }





    function update()
    {



        checkKey();  // checks what key has been pressed


            for (var i = snake.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
                snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
                snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x

            }

            switch (snakeDirection) {            // keys
                case "DOWN":
                    snake[0].y++;
                    break;

                case "UP":
                    snake[0].y--;
                    break;

                case "RIGHT":
                    snake[0].x++;
                    break;

                case "LEFT":
                    snake[0].x--;
                    break;
            }


            draw();                //draws all the stuff like food and snake

            checkCollisions();     // self explaintory name

    }


    function checkKey()         //Change the direction of the snake cant go  
    backwards too
    {
        if (keystate == Left && snakeDirection != "RIGHT" )
        {
            snakeDirection = "LEFT";
        }

        if (keystate == Up && snakeDirection != "DOWN")
        {
            snakeDirection = "UP";
        }

        if (keystate == Right && snakeDirection != "LEFT")
        {
            snakeDirection = "RIGHT";
        }

        if (keystate == Down && snakeDirection != "UP")
        {
            snakeDirection = "DOWN";
        }
    }
        function setFood()
        {    //WE ARE RUNNING  OUT OF FOOD WE NEED NEW PROVISIONS    
            var next = "true"
            do {
                foodX = Math.floor((Math.random() * Rows));

                foodY = Math.floor((Math.random() * Col));

                for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { // IT SUCKS WHEN I       
             CANT EAT FOOD BECAUSE ITS ALREADY INSIDE OF ME
                    if (snake[i].x == foodX && snake[i].y == foodY) {
                        next = "false"
                    }
                }
            }
            while (next == "false")

            draw();   // Pretty pictures
        }
    function checkCollisions()
    {
        for (var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {        // STOP hitting        
           yourself
            if (snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y) {
                init();
            }

        }

        if (snake[0].y < 0 || snake[0].y > Rows || snake[0].x < 0 || 
      snake[0].x > Col)  // you are forbidon to veture from the canvas
        {
        init();
        }

        if (snake[0].x == foodX && snake[0].y == foodY) {  //Yummy FOOD EAT 
       EAT EAT

            score++;

            document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "Score: " + score;

            setFood();

            snake.push({ x: null, y: null });  // I got fatter
        }

    }

    function draw()
    {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);   // clears 
      canvas

        context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";      // pretty colour for the head of 
    the snake
        context.fillRect(snake[0].x * cellWidth, snake[0].y * cellWidth, 
     cellWidth, cellHeight);

        context.fillStyle = "#09F";
        for (var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++)
        {
            context.fillRect(snake[i].x * cellWidth, snake[i].y * cellWidth, 
 cellWidth, cellHeight);
        }

        context.fillStyle = "#F90";   // FOOD FOOD FOOD FOOD

        context.fillRect(foodX * cellWidth, foodY * cellWidth, cellWidth, 
 cellHeight);
    }
    start(); // starts hence the name start
</script>
```

Comment: post the snippet and please let know what you tried

Comment: Please go through the [tour] and look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Answer (score 2):

OK not bad for a beginer if you wrote it all your self.

Your problem is with the keydown event. You are creating a new handler each time you tick. This will lead to a crash. You only need to create the event handler once for the page, it will remain active until you leave the page.

To fix your problem move adding the keyDown listener to just above the function Start, as shown below.

```
var snake = [];
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
    keystate = evt.keyCode; // checks key presses
});
function start(){
    init();
    Tick();
}
```

Also just a because to me it looks weird. true and false are not strings you dont need to put quotes around them. Though using them as strings still works.

You have

```
function setFood() { //WE ARE RUNNING  OUT OF FOOD WE NEED NEW PROVISIONS
    var next = "true"
    do {
        foodX = Math.floor((Math.random() * Rows));
        foodY = Math.floor((Math.random() * Col));
        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { 
            if (snake[i].x == foodX && snake[i].y == foodY) {
                next = "false"
            }
        }
    } while (next == "false")
    draw(); 
}
```

would be better written as follows

```
function setFood() { 
    var next = true;  // removed the qoutes
    do {
        foodX = Math.floor((Math.random() * Rows));
        foodY = Math.floor((Math.random() * Col));
        for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) { 
            if (snake[i].x == foodX && snake[i].y == foodY) {
                next = false; // removed the quotes.
                // no point continuing the for loop as you know you need to 
                // reposition the food so use the break token
                break; // breaks out of the closest loop
            }
        }
    } while ( !next )  // removed next == "false" and replaced with
                      // ! next.  "!" means "Not". do while next not true
    // you have the draw here but you draw every tick so it would be best if
    // you removed it as the next draw is less than 1/3 of a second away anyways
    // draw(); // removed needless draw
}
```

Good work. Hope you get a good mark for it.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you.